# Search for text nodes in Nokogiri

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

I searched for text nodes on a document fragment. This works, as the following snippet shows:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<p>foo</p>") 
doc.xpath('.//text()')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fe56c8c02a8 "foo">]
```

However, my root node may not have an tag like `<p>`, it could be a simple string like `"foo"`. Then this query fails.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("foo") 
doc.xpath('.//text()')
=> []
```

Changing the query to `doc.xpath('text()')` solves the problem.

Is there a query to combine both behaviour?

Comment: maybe "//p[text()='foo']" ?

Comment: `foo` is not a tag based on your example.

Comment: One remark: The string is not fixed, and the outer tag also not. I just want to find all text nodes in all children.

Comment: you want to find text nodes except `foo`?

Comment: I want to find **all** text nodes, regardless of its name.

Comment: A workaround is to wrap it in an additional element `parse("<root>#{original_xml}</root>")`. The not working example (`parse("foo")`) is not valid xml afaik (DocumentFragment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used Nokogiri, but in standard XPath, you should be able to just use the union operator:

```
doc.xpath('.//text() | text()')
```