# Using Nokogiri to read and count word output: Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, word-count

I'm using nokogiri to output a film script, and I'd like to be able to do a word count on that output.

I've adapted the answer from "[Getting viewable text words via Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129357/getting-viewable-text-words-via-nokogiri)", but when run, I get an `ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method 'frequencies')` error in this line:

```
puts frequencies(content)
```

This is the code I'm running, also I am still quite new to Rails, however I've tried my best to clean up the code for readability:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

class NokogiriController < ApplicationController
  page = 'http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Authors-Anonymous.html'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page))

  text = doc.css('b').remove
  text = doc.css('pre')

  content = text.to_s.scan(/\w+/)
  puts content.length, content.uniq.length, content.uniq.sort[0..8]

  def frequencies(content)
    Hash[
      content.group_by(&:downcase).map{ |word, instances|
        [word,instances.length]
        }.sort_by(&:last).reverse
      ]
  end

  puts frequencies(content)
end
```

Comment: doc.css returns a nodeset, assuming you wanted a string?

Comment: Just came across that myself: Yeah, I was wanting a string. I managed to output the content with doc.css, but I'm guessing it isn't as simple to work with from that point onwards

Comment: text.to_s.scan( .... ) should do it.

Comment: That's worked, however unfortunately that's unearthed an undefined method error.... Updated the question with suggestion + new problem

Comment: That's a bit naughty I'm not a debugging service. Think about what this is doing. When your controller gets required page.. to puts gets executed, shoukd be inside a method surely. Do you have a frequencies route?

Comment: Sorry: The SO help information says that comments should not be used to add new information and that I should edit my post instead of commenting. Things get a bit confusing after a bit. I'm not sure if this was what you were intending, but I added a helper_method for frequencies and a post route for frequencies - page loads, though it's showing a wrong number of arguments error (ala I'm not passing the argument "content" correctly). I think this would warrant a question update? A new question completely?

Comment: We add additional data and code to the original question, not comments, to avoid confusion and having detail being strewn across a page. Once a user has sufficient points they have the ability to see the revision history of a question, allowing them to easily see what was added when. It's useful sometimes to use a `---` in the question which adds a horizontal-rule to the question, delimiting sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at what you're doing:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Authors-Anonymous.html'))

doc.css('b').remove
text = doc.css('pre')
text 
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff6686df65c name="pre" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff6686df440 "\r\n\r\n\r\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff6686def7c "\r\n\r\n\r\n                          Written by\r\n\r\n                       David Congalton\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                                                       July 14 2012\r\n\r\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff6686deb1c "\r\n\r\n\r\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff6686de694 "\r\n\r\n">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff6686de20c ...

text.to_s 
# => "<pre>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                          Written by\r\n\r\n                       David Congalton\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                                                       July 14 2012\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    North Hayworth Avenue, off Sunset Boulevard. A quiet, tree-\r\n    lined residential street. Note the small apartment complex\r\n    set back from the curb.\r\n\r\n\r\n    Our narrator is HENRY OBERT (O-BURT)(30).\r\n\r\n               This is where...

text.to_s.scan(/\w+/) 
# => ["pre", "Written", "by", "David", "Congalton", "July", "14", "2012", "North", "Hayworth", "Avenue", "off", "Sunset", "Boulevard", "A", "quiet", "tree", "lined", "residential", "street", "Note", "the", "small", "apartment", "complex", "set", "back", "from", "the", "curb", "Our", "narrator", "is", "HENRY", "OBERT", "O", "BURT", "30", "This", "is", "where", "where", "F", "Scott", "Fitzgerald", "died", "on", "December", "21", "1940", "INSERT", "ARCHIVAL", "PHOTOS", "of", "Fitzgerald", "H...
```

You're capturing the tags, parameters to those, plus the embedded text as a NodeSet, AKA, an array of Nodes. I don't think you want to do that.

Instead, I'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def frequencies(content)
  Hash[
    content.group_by(&:downcase).map{ |word, instances|
      [word,instances.length]
      }.sort_by(&:last).reverse
    ]
end

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Authors-Anonymous.html'))

doc.css('b').remove
text = doc.css('pre').map(&:text)
text 
# => ["\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                          Written by\r\n\r\n                       David Congalton\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                                                       July 14 2012\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    North Hayworth Avenue, off Sunset Boulevard. A quiet, tree-\r\n    lined residential street. Note the small apartment complex\r\n    set back from the curb.\r\n\r\n\r\n    Our narrator is HENRY OBERT (O-BURT)(30).\r\n\r\n               This is where whe...

text.join(' ')
# => "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                          Written by\r\n\r\n                       David Congalton\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n                                                       July 14 2012\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    North Hayworth Avenue, off Sunset Boulevard. A quiet, tree-\r\n    lined residential street. Note the small apartment complex\r\n    set back from the curb.\r\n\r\n\r\n    Our narrator is HENRY OBERT (O-BURT)(30).\r\n\r\n               This is where wher...

content = text.join(' ').scan(/\w+/) 
# => ["Written", "by", "David", "Congalton", "July", "14", "2012", "North", "Hayworth", "Avenue", "off", "Sunset", "Boulevard", "A", "quiet", "tree", "lined", "residential", "street", "Note", "the", "small", "apartment", "complex", "set", "back", "from", "the", "curb", "Our", "narrator", "is", "HENRY", "OBERT", "O", "BURT", "30", "This", "is", "where", "where", "F", "Scott", "Fitzgerald", "died", "on", "December", "21", "1940", "INSERT", "ARCHIVAL", "PHOTOS", "of", "Fitzgerald", "His", "w...

frequencies(content)
# => {"the"=>827, "to"=>486, "i"=>398, "a"=>397, "s"=>284, "and"=>279, "in"=>273, "of"=>238, "hannah"=>234, "you"=>232, "henry"=>223, "it"=>214, "on"=>207, "her"=>200, "is"=>192, "his"=>178, "he"=>165, "for"=>162, "t"=>152, "that"=>151, "colette"=>148, "she"=>142, "at"=>137, "john"=>133, "alan"=>118, "this"=>112, "my"=>109, "up"=>105, "all"=>88, "william"=>88, "as"=>85, "what"=>84, "with"=>84, "but"=>83, "be"=>76, "camera"=>76, "not"=>74, "one"=>74, "can"=>73, "out"=>70, "m"=>69, "from"=>...
```

I inserted some additional steps so you can see what is being returned more easily. You can ignore those.

The idea is to ignore the tags, except to use them to grab their text content, which is what `map(&:text)` does.

Things to watch out for:

- `\w` doesn't mean `[a-z0-9]`, it means `[a-z0-9_]` which matches variable names, not what we'd consider typical words.
- Values that are pure digits, such as "14" and "2012" needlessly clutter the results. Using [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-reject) to remove all-digit entries would probably be good because those aren't usually very useful when determining keywords and such.

Comment: I've been using your answer as a spring board to finding out more, it's been incredibly useful. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, good. That's what I hope to accomplish when answering. Learn, learn more, learn even more, then start teaching others what you've learned.