# How to retrieve gross information from a wikipedia movie page with nokogiri (ruby)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Nokogiri usually parses information by searching html tags(elements), but how is it possible to parse information just from the text written on the page?

For example, I would like to parse a gross information from

**Link:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(1997_film)

I want to retrieve the gross information from the text below:

*Thursday, October 1, 1998* with a final domestic gross of *$600,788,188*

How can I do this with nokogiri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to answer, since it's a very open question. You are faced with two different problems. One is how to parse the text, the other is how to find the information you are looking for.

## How to parse Wikipedia

My initial approach would be to get the text from the HTML page, and then use regex to look for the information I need. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161807/5152338) is a good place to start:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(IO.read 'myfile.html')
text  = html.at('body').inner_text
```

You first use Nokogiri to fetch a HTML page (in your case from a URL) and then get the text on that page using `inner_text`. Once you have the text, you can use any method that can extract information from a string. I would use a regex:

```
> /.*gross of \$([0-9,]+).*/.match(text)[1]
=> "600,788,188"
```

This is only an example, but it should allow you to move in the right direction.

## How to find the correct information

What might be a problem for you is that the regex above only works if the gross revenue is always in the same format, i.e. *gross of $600,788,188*. The regex is not able to intelligently analyze the page and figure out which amount of money is the domestic gross revenue.

My guess is that this is also why your question was down voted. While it is technically not difficult to extract information from a single page, writing an algorithm that intelligently parses different websites to extract the same piece of information from them is incredibly difficult.

You might be better off looking at IMDB for example, which list *Box Office* revenue for almost all movies in a very repeatable pattern. Check out the entry for Titanic: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338

It would get even easier if you used an API. JSON is much easier to process programmatically than HTML, and if you google for IMDB and API, you should find a few resources that explain how to do this.